# Displaying a Play button on Multiple videos on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm a complete novice when it comes to Javascript (& copy and paste kind of guy ;)... so I'm having a bit of a problem trying to figure out how to do the following:

- I've got a slideshow gallery that has 2 mp4 videos in the same set
- I've found some javascript that overlays a play button on the mp4 video
- However... the code work fine when I have one video - but when I place the 2nd video, I'm failing to get the overlaid arrows working on both...

There's an obvious problem with clashing classes / variables (or something to that effect) - but I can't figure it out...

HTML:

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <div class="video-wrapper">
        <video controls preload="metadata" class="pure-img video" poster="assets/posters/poster_adele-BBC.jpg">
            <source src="http://d1wv6pnepp7p5s.cloudfront.net/AA_BBC_ALL_CUTDOWN_02.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
        </video>
    </div>
</div>         

<div class="swiper-slide">
    <div class="video-wrapper-two">
        <video controls preload="metadata" class="pure-img video" poster="assets/posters/poster_adele-BBC.jpg">
            <source src="http://d1wv6pnepp7p5s.cloudfront.net/AA_BBC_ALL_CUTDOWN_02.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>

var videoPlayButton,
videoWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('video-wrapper')[0],
video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0],
videoMethods = {
    renderVideoPlayButton: function() {
        if (videoWrapper.contains(video)) {
            this.formatVideoPlayButton()
            video.classList.add('has-media-controls-hidden')
            videoPlayButton = document.getElementsByClassName('video-overlay-play-button')[0]
            videoPlayButton.addEventListener('click', this.hideVideoPlayButton)
        }
    },

    formatVideoPlayButton: function() {
        videoWrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '\
            <svg class="video-overlay-play-button" viewBox="0 0 200 200" alt="Play video">\
                <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" fill="#000" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff"/>\
                <polygon points="70, 55 70, 145 145, 100" fill="#fff"/>\
            </svg>\
        ')
    },

    hideVideoPlayButton: function() {
        video.play()
        videoPlayButton.classList.add('is-hidden')
        video.classList.remove('has-media-controls-hidden')
        video.setAttribute('controls', 'controls')
    }
}

videoMethods.renderVideoPlayButton()

</script>
```

The javascript handles the 1st wrapper fine, I'm just having difficulty getting the 2nd wrapper to display the Play button correctly...

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="video-wrapper-two">
                    <video controls preload="metadata" class="pure-img video" poster="assets/posters/poster_adele-BBC.jpg">
                        <source src="http://d1wv6pnepp7p5s.cloudfront.net/AA_BBC_ALL_CUTDOWN_02.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>`

So let's focus on these lines.
Your first error in HTML is renaming the `'video-wrapper'` class to `'video-wrapper-two'` on the second element. It must be the same if you plan to reuse the elements in JavaScript.

Your second error is referencing only the first `'video-wrapper'` from your array instead of getting them all
    videoWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('video-wrapper')[0]

Instead you would need this

```
videoWrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('video-wrapper');
videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
```

The third problem needs a bit more code, because at the moment you baked in the single videoElement item into your functions, so you can't call it on each. So instead of referencing the videos from the function, you have to pass it as a reference (as a function parameter) so you could do something like this when you call it

```
for(var i = 0; i < videWrappers.length; i++){
    // it will be called on each video element one by one
    videoMethods.renderVideoPlayButton(videoWrappers[i], video[i]); 
}
```

The key point is to never bake variables into your functions, instead always use function parameters so you can reuse those functions whenever you need it.

Comment: HI - Where would that last snippet code go in the js file? Sorry - I'm a complete novice... 

http://warrenchapmanfilms.com/project-new-order-singularity_1.html

Comment: Just below the variable declarations as it appears on the screen. You do not have to move around anything. Also if you want you can combine everything in one html file just make sure to wrap the JS code like
    <script>/*Copy paste those 2 vars and the for loop here*/
    </script>

at the very end of the html page.

Also please stop use the excuse of "I'm a complete novice." all the time. Look up the basics on Google and YouTube. It is free. We can help you with problems but cannot teach you the basics here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is

```
videoWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('video-wrapper')[0],
video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0],
```

It specify first set only

You should make it as a function and invoke twice.

```js
var videoPlayButton;
function addMethod(video,videoWrapper){
 return {
    renderVideoPlayButton: function() {
      if (videoWrapper.contains(video)) {
        this.formatVideoPlayButton()
        video.classList.add('has-media-controls-hidden')
        videoPlayButton = document.getElementsByClassName('video-overlay-play-button')[0]
        videoPlayButton.addEventListener('click', this.hideVideoPlayButton)
      }
    },

    formatVideoPlayButton: function() {
      videoWrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '\
            <svg class="video-overlay-play-button" viewBox="0 0 200 200" alt="Play video">\
                <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" fill="#000" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff"/>\
                <polygon points="70, 55 70, 145 145, 100" fill="#fff"/>\
            </svg>\
        ')
    },

    hideVideoPlayButton: function() {
      video.play()
      videoPlayButton.classList.add('is-hidden')
      video.classList.remove('has-media-controls-hidden')
      video.setAttribute('controls', 'controls')
    }
  }
}

addMethod(document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0],document.getElementsByClassName('video-wrapper')[0]).renderVideoPlayButton();
addMethod(document.getElementsByTagName('video')[1],document.getElementsByClassName('video-wrapper-two')[0]).renderVideoPlayButton();
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slide">
  <div class="video-wrapper">
    <video controls preload="metadata" class="pure-img video" poster="assets/posters/poster_adele-BBC.jpg">
                        <source src="http://d1wv6pnepp7p5s.cloudfront.net/AA_BBC_ALL_CUTDOWN_02.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
                    </video>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="swiper-slide">
  <div class="video-wrapper-two">
    <video controls preload="metadata" class="pure-img video" poster="assets/posters/poster_adele-BBC.jpg">
                        <source src="http://d1wv6pnepp7p5s.cloudfront.net/AA_BBC_ALL_CUTDOWN_02.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
                    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code on this page:

[http://warrenchapmanfilms.com/project-award-rts.html ], but there still seems to be an issue, which is:

- The play button on the first video is fine.
- The play button on the 2nd video is static, overlays both videos, and doesn't allow either video to be played...

Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: I meant this page: http://warrenchapmanfilms.com/project-award-rts_1.html ... Thanks...